# 401 Unauthorized Error when Calling Microsoft Graph API's "/me/todo/lists" Endpoint Using MSAL with NestJS

Tags: azure, nestjs

I've been facing an issue when trying to fetch user's to-do lists from Microsoft Graph API in my NestJS application.

Here is a summary of my setup:

1. I have created an `MsGraphService` that initializes a ConfidentialClientApplication using `@azure/msal-node`. The configuration includes `clientId`, `clientSecret`, and `authority`.
2. I am using `@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client` to generate a Graph client. The authentication provider acquires tokens silently. I've enabled `forceRefresh: true` to ensure fresh tokens are fetched each time.
3. I have another `TodoService` that invokes the Microsoft Graph API's `/me/todo/lists` endpoint using the aforementioned `MsGraphService`.

I am invoking `getTodos` from `TodoService` in a GraphQL resolver, `TodoResolver`.

Here are the primary methods:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MsGraphService {
  private readonly msalConfig: Configuration;
  private readonly msalClient: ConfidentialClientApplication;

  public readonly scopes: string[] = [
    'Tasks.Read',
    'Tasks.ReadWrite',
    'User.Read',
    'User.ReadWrite',
    'email',
    'openid',
    'profile',
  ];
  public readonly redirectUri: string;

  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    this.msalConfig = {
      auth: {
        clientId: configService.getOrThrow('OAUTH_CLIENT_ID') || '',
        clientSecret: configService.getOrThrow('OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${this.configService.getOrThrow(
          'OAUTH_TENANT_ID',
        )}`,
      },
      system: {
        loggerOptions: {
          loggerCallback(loglevel, message, containsPii) {
            Logger.debug(message, 'MsGraphService');
          },
          piiLoggingEnabled: false,
          logLevel: 3,
        },
      },
    };

    this.msalClient = new ConfidentialClientApplication(this.msalConfig);

    this.redirectUri = this.configService.get(
      'OAUTH_REDIRECT_URI',
      'http://localhost:3000/ms-graph/callback',
    );
  }

  public GraphClient(userId: string): Client {
    const client = Client.init({
      authProvider: async (done) => {
        try {
          const account = await this.msalClient
            .getTokenCache()
            .getAccountByHomeId(userId);

          if (!account) {
            done('account not defined', null);
            return;
          }

          const response = await this.msalClient.acquireTokenSilent({
            scopes: this.scopes,
            account,
            forceRefresh: true
          });

          done(null, response.accessToken);
          Logger.debug(response, 'MsGraphService');
        } catch (err) {
          done(err, null);
        }
      },
    });

    return client;
  }
}
```

```js
getTodos(userId: string) {
    try {
      return this.msService.GraphClient(userId).api(`/me/todo/lists`);
    } catch (err) {
      Logger.error(err);
    }
  }
```

However, when invoking this setup, I'm encountering a 401 Unauthorized error from the Graph API:

```
{
  statusCode: 401,
  code: 'UnknownError',
  requestId: '97df2091-d1c6-43c9-b576-0c32ac123950',
  date: 2023-08-18T06:28:28.000Z,
  body: '{"code":"UnknownError","message":"","innerError":{"date":"2023-08-18T08:28:28","request-id":"97df2091-d1c6-43c9-b576-0c32ac123950","client-request-id":"a3a4a284-4398-73df-df1d-3e3f47e02268"}}'
}
```

I've ensured the following:

The necessary permissions (`Tasks.Read`, `Tasks.ReadWrite`, etc.) are requested in the scopes.
The application is registered correctly in the Azure Portal, and the necessary API permissions have been granted.
I'm unable to pinpoint the reason behind this 401 Unauthorized error, especially since the error message from the Graph API is an UnknownError.

In addition, here are the permissions I gave to the client:
[image: Permissions]

Could anyone provide insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Thank you!

Comment: What account type you are using to fetch details?

Comment: Can you also decode the access token and check if the scopes are displayed with correct aud?

Comment: sure @Rukmini, if I understood you correct, in the overview tab I see "Supported account types: All Microsoft account users". Also in the manifest: `"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount"`.


The access token also contains the correct scopes:


`"scp": "Calendars.Read Calendars.ReadWrite email openid OrgSettings-Todo.Read.All OrgSettings-Todo.ReadWrite.All profile Tasks.Read Tasks.ReadWrite User.Read User.ReadWrite"`

Comment: I am referring to `aud` which must be Microsoft Graph and make sure that the access token is not expired

Comment: I am not sure how would I make sure this is the right `aud`, but this is just what's in the jwt:
`"aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"`.

How ever, since you mentioned it must be "Microsoft Graph", I feel this might the wrong part. which I think should have been correctly set since I'm using the default msal configs... maybe I'm wrong

Comment: No it is correct aud is Microsoft Graph only "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" is correct

Comment: Are you sure access token is not expired?

Comment: Yes, I made sure about that, `"exp": 1692359276`, which is in around an hour in my tz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254952/discussion-between-aien-saidi-and-rukmini).